# Can't connect to AMQP twice in order to send messages to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem connecting to the AMQP in my rSpec testing. I have code like this:

```
Module Rabbit
  Class Client

    def start
      EventMachine.run do
        connection = AMQP.connect(Settings_object) #it holds host, username and password information

         channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
         channel.queue("queue_name", :durable => true)
         channel.default_exchange.publish("A test message", :routing_key => "queue_name")    

      end
    end 
 end


 Module Esper
  Class Server

    def start
      EventMachine.run do
        connection = AMQP.connect(Settings_object) #it holds host, username and password information

       =begin
        Some code to subscribe to queues
       =end

      end
    end 
 end
```

My problem is when I run the rspec:

```
 @client = Rabbit::Client.new
 @server = Esper::Server.new

 Thread.new do
   @client.start
 end
 Thread.new do
   @server.start
 end
```

At first Client is able to connect to the AMQP, and the Server doesn't , but when I run it for the second time, then the Client can't connect to the server. I can't see to overcome this problem. I don't see a reason why would Client stop connecting when I run it on the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is that new for every queue for AMQP needs to have it's separate connection. For example:

```
queue1_connectom = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
queue2_connectom = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
```

And use it like that.

But overall for this whole situation is to use `deamon-kit` gem. It separates the AMQP into a separate application and the AMQP connections are handled within that "application" or better yet - A Deamon.

It also has a generator for AMQP so good thing would be to use that.